# Displaying words one by one

Tags: ios, swift

looking for a basic way to display a group of text one by one rapidly and be able to moderate the speed it is displayed - in swift, such as the the gif provided.

[gif link](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjwqsuqi_HcAhWCb1AKHfqeDLsQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2Fthread-forums-random-12AT4ReBiyksBq&psig=AOvVaw1mGKe0Rhbek7GlZvp0Vpy2&ust=1534492260096269)

Comment: Please be aware that SO isn't a code writing service - please show what research you've undertaken, you've already tried, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let lbl = UILabel()

lbl.frame = view.frame

view.addSubview(lbl)

let str  = "We are here"

let arr =  str.components(separatedBy: " ")

var counter = 0

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { (t) in

    lbl.text = arr[counter]

    counter += 1

    if counter == arr.count {

        t.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Also you can make use of [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink)

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: insertTimeIntervalhere, target: self, selector: #selector(functionThatChangesLabelTextToNextWord), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You can check if the word is last you want to display, and then call:
`timer.invalidate()`